# creating a highscore with file io in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have been attempting to create a highscore with file.io but have not been able to do it. This is the code I have.

```
public void highScore ()
{
    int highScore = 0;
    String line = "";
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("highScores"));
        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null)                 // read the score file line by line
        {
            try
            {
                int score = Integer.parseInt (line); // parse each line as an int
                if (score > highScore)                       // and keep track of the largest
                {
                    highScore = score;
                }
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e1)
            {
                // ignore invalid scores
                //System.err.println("ignoring invalid score: " + line);
            }
            line = reader.readLine ();
        }
        reader.close ();

    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.err.println ("ERROR reading scores from file");
    }
    c.println (highScore);
}
```

My text file has only numbers in it in each line

Comment: What does the code do? What is it supposed to do? What is it doing wrong? Is there an error? What are the inputs?

Comment: @Tunaki the code is supposed to categorize the highscores from highest to lowest and then display it in the program, bur instead it gives me an error and displays a "0". the inputs i have in the text file are:
2
4
8
6
10

Comment: Remove ```line = reader.readLine ();``` at the end of while loop.

Comment: Also you should print the stacktrace of the exception in the catch block instead of "Error" so that at least you know what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you get:

> "ERROR reading scores from file"

You should fix your filename extension:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("highScores.txt"));
```

and make sure the file lies in the project's folder.

Also, notice you read two lines from the file each time, at the end of the while loop and in the while header, so delete `line = reader.readLine ();` at the end of the loop.

Comment: thanks! also, how can i output them for greatest to least now that i have the highest of them all?

Comment: In that case, you should use a list to contain all of the values while reading, and then print it out after sorting it in descending order.

Comment: once all the values are read, should i put them in an array to then sort them out? I'm a little confused at how I'm supposed to approach this situation

Comment: It's easier to use a list, and after inserting all the value use **Collections.sort** but you can also use an array.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note the best practice would be catching `Exception`. Right now you are just trying to catch `IOException`, do something like

```
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As Exception is super class of all exceptions you can see if the code is breaking because of some other exception (in this case it might be `FileNotFoundException`)

and printing the stack tarce will help you point out the issue with line number in the code where exactly you are getting an exception.